# Weird object returned from AJAX request

Tags: ajax

I have this method:

```
    var chineseCurrency = getChinese();
    function getChinese(){
        return $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "https://www.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/usd-cny"
        });
    }
```

That is what printed when `console.log(chineseCurrency);`:

[image]

I am not able to make `chineseCurrency` equal to `"price"`, so it would be `"6.80071377"`. How can I do that? Tried `chineseCurrency.responseText`, nope, `chineseCurrency['responseText']`, nope. Tried to `JSON.parse(chineseCurrency)`, nope. Nothing works!

Sorry if repeated, couldn't find any answer at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Data that is received as response to asynchronous ajax call cannot be returned  from the function that calls `$.ajax`. What you are returning is `XMLHttpRequest` object (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that is far from the desired data.

```
var chineseCurrency = null;
function getChinese(){
    return $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "https://www.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/usd-cny",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success1: chineseCurrency=" + chineseCurrency); 
            chineseCurrency = data.ticker.price;
            alert("success2: chineseCurrency=" + chineseCurrency);
            // do what you need with chineseCurrency 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: все равно не работает.

Comment: @SeattleSam Что не работает? Покажите исправленый код, который не работает. Вы используете переменную `chineseCurrency` сразу после вызова `getChinese`?

Comment: Если я делаю именно так, то вне функции, `chineseCurrency` не виден. Вы знаете, дело в том, что эта функция, в свою очередь, находится в функции, которая использует `callback`. Может быть в этом дело?

Comment: Хорошо, а как манипулировать объект, который я указал в вопросе? Как я могу взять нужные мне данные?

Comment: @SeattleSam Вы не должны "манипулировать" `XMLHttpRequest`. Важно понять, что до выполнения обработчика `success`, `chineseCurrency` нельзя использовать. Я, собственно, хотел это подчеркнуть перенесением объявления этой переменной внутрь `success: function(data) { ... }`. Если она нужна Вам снаружи - посмотрите на исправленный код. Важно не рассчитывать на то, что в этой переменной окажется значение до вызова `success`. А вызывается `success` не Вашим кодом, а `jQuery.ajax`ом.

Comment: null так и остается. Даже не знаю как мне extract нужный price. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @SeattleSam - Может, Вы добавите в Ваш вопрос код, который вызывает `getChinese` и использует `chineseCurrency` (с учетом последних исправлений), пока мне не надоело об этом просить :) ?

Comment: Игорь, все норм. Я разобрался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking the data from that is returned from the Ajax call. instead you are just returning the ajax object.

Change your code to :

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        context: this,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "https://www.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/usd-cny"
        data    :{},
        error   : function(data)
        {
            console.log('error occured when trying to find the from city');
        },
        success : function(data) 
        {
           console.log(data); //This is what you should return from the function. 
        }
   });
```

Comment: thanks. But how can I make it equal to `chineseCurrency`? in `success`? I tried like `chineseCurrency = data`, but not working.

Comment: data.ticket['price'] would return the price

Comment: First console log this data and make changes to your function to return this value.

Comment: "make ... your function to return this value" - what function? `data.ticket['price']` cannot be returned from the function that calls asynchronous ajax

Comment: Yes. I just figured it out. So its better to use the ajax call outside the function a d wait for the ajax response.

Comment: guys, what should I do? )